# Formulario POST no envia((failed)net::ERR_FAILED)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario que envía unos datos por Post antes de enviarlo tengo 3 funciones para hacer unas validaciones y reunir unos datos para previamente enviarlos, pero al enviarlos en navegador me cancela dicho envió con la foto que adjunto continuación
[image: Imagen con la falla]

Estuve revisando la falla y según encontré es por que esas 3 funciones cancelan el envió, pero cuando en Google lo ejecuto con punto de interrupción estos datos si se envían por eso no se que puede estar pasando y como puedo solucionarlo, agradezco de su ayuda, para saber si el error es en el codigo y si me ayudarían a corregirlo gracias.

Adjunto el codigo

```js
function enviar() {
            
            var validacion = this.validar();
            if (validacion[0] == "true") {
                var totalResponse = this.validarRespuestas();
                this.sendPost(totalResponse);
                document.formQuiz.action = "grade.php";
                document.formQuiz.target = "_blank";
                document.formQuiz.submit();
                return true;
            } else {
                alert(validacion[1]);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function validar() {
            var inputPaternNombre = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;
            var inputPaternPhone = /^[0-9_-]{10,11}$/;
            var inputPaternEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

            var inputValNombre = document.getElementById("first_name").value
            var inputValPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value
            var inputValemail = document.getElementById("email").value
            
            var pruebaNombre = inputPaternNombre.test(inputValNombre);
            var pruebaEmail = inputPaternEmail.test(inputValemail);
            var pruebaPhone = inputPaternPhone.test(inputValPhone);

            var ValideFields = false;
            //var form = document.getElementById("formSalesForces");
            var msg = [];

            if (pruebaEmail == true && pruebaNombre == true && pruebaPhone == true) {
                msg.push("true");
            } else {
                msg.push("false");
            }

            if (!pruebaEmail) {
                msg.push("Ingrese un Correo Electrónico válido");
            }

            if (!pruebaNombre) {
                msg.push("Ingrese un Nombre con caracteres válidos");
            }

            if (!pruebaPhone) {
                msg.push("Ingrese un Teléfono con caracteres válidos, únicamente números, mínimo 10 máximo 11");
            }

            return msg;
        }

        function validarRespuestas(){
            
            var answerTotal = 0;
            
            var answer1 = document.getElementsByName('question-1-answers');
            var answer2 = document.getElementsByName('question-2-answers');
            var answer3 = document.getElementsByName('question-3-answers');
            var answer4 = document.getElementsByName('question-4-answers');
            var answer5 = document.getElementsByName('question-5-answers');
            var answer6 = document.getElementsByName('question-6-answers');
            var answer7 = document.getElementsByName('question-7-answers');
            var answer8 = document.getElementsByName('question-8-answers');
            var answer9 = document.getElementsByName('question-9-answers');
            var answer10 = document.getElementsByName('question-10-answers');
            
            if(answer1[0].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer2[1].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer3[0].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer4[0].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer5[1].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer6[0].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer7[1].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer8[2].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer9[2].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            if(answer10[0].checked){
                answerTotal ++;
            }
            return answerTotal;
        }

        function sendPost(totalAnswer){
            var inputValemail = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var inputValNombre = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
            var inputValPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
            var inputValCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
            var inputValCountrySegmentation = document.getElementById("Country_Segmentation__c").value;
            var inputUrlForm = document.getElementById("Form_URL__c").value;
            var inputCampaignSource = document.getElementById("Campaign_Source__c").value;
            var inputCampaignName = document.getElementById("Campaign_Name__c").value;
            var inputCampaignMedium = document.getElementById("Campaign_Medium__c").value;

            var formBody = [];
            
            formBody.push("oid="+constants.oid);
            formBody.push("retURL="+constants.retURL);
            formBody.push("recordType="+constants.recordType);
            formBody.push("status="+constants.status);
            formBody.push("lead_source="+constants.leadSource);
            formBody.push("Country_Segmentation__c="+inputValCountrySegmentation);
            formBody.push("country="+inputValCountry);
            formBody.push("B2C_Lead__c"+constants.b2cLead);
            formBody.push("Experiment__c"+constants.experiment);
            formBody.push("Form_URL__c="+inputUrlForm);
            formBody.push("Google_Analytics_Client_ID__c"+constants.googleAnalyticsClientID);
            formBody.push("Campaign_Source__c="+inputCampaignSource);
            formBody.push("Campaign_Name__c="+inputCampaignName);
            formBody.push("Campaign_Medium__c="+inputCampaignMedium);
            formBody.push("Class_Type__c="+constants.classType);
            formBody.push("description= Total: "+totalAnswer);
            formBody.push("first_name="+inputValNombre);
            formBody.push("phone="+inputValPhone);
            formBody.push("email="+inputValemail);
            
            formBody = formBody.join("&");
        
           
            
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log("2***** OK ********", );
                    
                }
            };
            
            xhttp.open("POST", "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            xhttp.send(formBody);
            
        }

        const btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btn')
        var formulario = 1
        btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', enviarFormulario)
        function enviarFormulario() {
            if (formulario === 1) {
                var validate = function() {
                    var form = document.getElementById("formSalesForces");
                    if (!form.phone.value || isNaN(parseInt(form.phone.value))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (form.first_name.value.length < 40) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var emailRegex = /^\w+@\w+\.\w+$/;
                    if (!form.email.value.match(emailRegex)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                /* alert('Formulario 1') */
                console.log('')
                
                formulario++
            } else {
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-1-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 1 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-2-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 2 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-3-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 3 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-4-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 4 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-5-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 5 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-6-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 6 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-7-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 7 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-8-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 8 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-9-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 9 ');
                }
                if (!$("#formQuiz input[name='question-10-answers']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Seleccione una opción en la pregunta 10 ');
                }
                return true;
                alert('Formulario 2')
            }
        }
        
        submit = "";
        function activar(formulario, submit) {
            cont = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < formulario.elements.length; i++) {
                if (formulario.elements[i].value != "") {
                    cont = cont + 1;
                }
                if (submit == "") {
                    if (formulario.elements[i].type == "submit") {
                        submit = formulario.elements[i].name;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (cont == formulario.elements.length) {
                formulario.submit.disabled = false;
            } else {
                formulario.submit.disabled = true;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor_forms">
            <div class="page-wrap">
                <!-- <form name="formQuiz" id="formQuiz" onkeyup="activar(this);" method="post" action="grade.php"
                    target="_blank"> -->
                     <form name="formQuiz" id="formQuiz">
                    <ol class="test_bord">
                        <li>
                            <h3>* What are your obligations at work?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) I have to schedule meetings with my clients </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) I needs to play videogames</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-1-answers-C">C) I must to present reports</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-D" value="D"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-1-answers-D">D) I had to spoke with my boss</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* How long does it take you to get to work?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-2-answers-A">A) It took me one hour</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-2-answers-B">B) It takes me about an hour</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-2-answers-C">C) It does take me one hour</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* What will you be doing in five years?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-3-answers-A">A) I will be working in Google</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-3-answers-B">B) I am going to play guitar</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-3-answers-C">C) I will buy a car</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* By the time you arrived here, had you had breakfast?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-4-answers-A">A) Yes, I had had breakfast</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-4-answers-B">B) No, I haven’t have breakfast</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-4-answers-C">C) No, I wont have it</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* How long have you lived in Bogota?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-5-answers-A">A) I has lived in Bogota since 1982</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-5-answers-B">B) I have lived in Bogota, since I was born</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-5-answers-C">C) I haven’t live in Bogota</label>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* What language is spoken in China?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-6-answers-A">A) Mandarin is spoken in China</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-6-answers-B">B) In China, they spoke Spanish</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-6-answers-C">C) In China, they spoke Italian</label>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* Tell me, what will you do if you finish work early today?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-7-answers-A">A) I used to have been studying</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-7-answers-B">B) I will go to a party</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-7-answers-C">C) I have gone to my moms house</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* What are you used to doing every Sunday?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-8-answers-A">A) I use to have clean my apartment</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-8-answers-B">B) I used to been in the gym</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" />
                                <label for="question-8-answers-C">C) I am used to spending time with my family</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* Can you describe yourself?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-9-answers-A">A) No, I don’t</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-9-answers-B">B) No, I wont</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-9-answers-C">C) Yes, I can</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>* How much traffic is there in your city?</h3>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-A" value="A" required
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-10-answers-A">A) There is a lot of traffic in my city</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-B" value="B"
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-10-answers-B">B) There is many traffic in my city</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-C" value="C"
                                    class="radiobig" / />
                                <label for="question-10-answers-C">C) There cars, buses and taxis</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </form>
               
                <form name="formSalesForces" id="formSalesForces"
                    onkeyup="activar(this);" onsubmit="return enviarFormulario()"
                    onsubmit="return makeSearch()" class="" method="post">
                    <div class="mve-wrapper text-left">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Country_Segmentation__c" name="Country_Segmentation__c" value="Colombia">
                        <input type="hidden" id="country" name="country" value="Colombia">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Form_URL__c" name="Form_URL__c" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Campaign_Source__c" name="Campaign_Source__c" value="undefined">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Campaign_Name__c" name="Campaign_Name__c" value="undefined">
                        <input type="hidden" id="Campaign_Medium__c" name="Campaign_Medium__c" value="undefined">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Envíanos tus datos para conocer tu nivel de inglés.</h2>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                <label for="first_name" class="">Nombre Completo</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required=""
                                    aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                <label for="phone" class="">Teléfono</label>
                                <input id="phone" class="form-control" maxlength="11" name="phone" type="tel" required=""
                                    aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                <label for="email" class="">Correo electrónico</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required=""
                                    aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="aH6_fO8H_b_" data-key="max-checkbox__input" name="Email_Opt_In__c"
                                value="1" class="Checkboxstyle__Input-sc-1ob6epv-1 kLTiif" checked="">
                            <label for="contacto" class="">¿Quisiera ser contactado por nuestro asesor académico? <br>
                                <em><span style="font-size: 10pt;">Para conocer tu nivel de inglés y darte mayor información de nuestros programas.</span></em></label>
                            <br>
                            <!-- <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="mayorinfo" value="si" required> SI<br></label>
                                <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="mayorinfo" value="no"> NO<br></label>  -->
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            <span style="font-size: 10pt;">
                                Al momento de dar click en&nbsp;<strong>"Enviar"</strong> está aceptando nuestra <span
                                    style="color: #99ccff;">
                                    <a href=" rel="nofollow"
                                        style="color: #99ccff;" target="_blank">
                                        Política de Privacidad</a></span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="bot_for" id="btn" onclick="return enviar();" type="submit" name="submit"
                                value="Enviar Datos" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <a class="logo2" href="#">
                
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código para entender el error y que puedan ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Hola ya agregue el código, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra el error en consola, quizá te arroje el motivo exacto por el que el código falla, parece ser un problema de red o en el servidor. Pon esta parte con un control de errores: `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log("2***** OK ********", );
                    
                } else { console.log("Error: "+xhttp.status+ xhttp.statusText); }
            };`

Comment: Pude realizar la prueba que me mencionas me arroja lo siguientes según veo tiene que ver con las funciones pero no estoy seguro, me dice


HR failed loading: POST "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8".
sendPost @ mx_clientes.php:439
enviar @ mx_clientes.php:296
onclick @ mx_clientes.php:272

Comment: Puede que `formBody` tenga una forma incorrecta. Haz un test del mismo mediante `console.log(formBody);` Como siempre digo: depurar, depurar, depurarlo todo. Debes mostrar cada cosa que falla y analizarla.